# Prevent full project clean / rebuild in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I've found that ever since upgrading to version 4 (I currently have Luna / 4.4.2, on OSX) Eclipse does a full clean & build on a project far more often than necessary.  There seems to be no relation between how much code I change and what it chooses to do.  I've seen it clean & rebuild after touching only comment lines.  Is there a way to have it clean only when instructed?

I already have "Build automatically" disabled but this only affects when it builds, not how much.

Thanks,
Jon