# Eclipse: full rebuild triggered

Tags: java, eclipse, build

I'd like to get some information to debug a problem I am having, being that Eclipse rebuilds everything in my open Java-only project instead of just recompiling incrementally. Not restarting Eclipse or anything, just saving a file or whatever.

What exact conditions in Eclipse triggers a full rebuild? Seems to be sometimes when you rename or move compilation units, and sometimes this persists even after the first full rebuild after the move/rename.

Is there any way to get Eclipse to show the reason it is rebuilding? Maybe there is some logging that could provide useful information?

Sometimes the problem goes away on its own after a few bouts, sometimes after some indeterminate combination of: closing the project, cleaning the project, quitting the Eclipse app, touching the .classpath file.

Automatic rebuild is *not* turned on.

---

Similar questions below.

---

[Why does Eclipse sometimes rebuild the whole workspace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379558/why-does-eclipse-sometimes-rebuild-the-whole-workspace)

Note: 'After I start Eclipse ...'

---

[Prevent full project clean / rebuild in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30781735/prevent-full-project-clean-rebuild-in-eclipse)

No answers.

---

[Eclipse: can I keep progress dialog from blocking UI somehow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55049441/eclipse-can-i-keep-progress-dialog-from-blocking-ui-somehow)

Me earlier, trying to mitigate some of the impact.

Comment: Is it a single project, multiple projects, do they use Maven?  I've found that in some situations (dozens of projects) with builders other than the Java builder, it is possible to trigger loops (ie, a builder modifies resources, which triggers another builder modifying the same resources, which triggers the first builder again).  You may want to try stripping your project a bit (making some jar dependencies) and seeing if you can find when the problem disappears -- you may have a circular dependency in the building process somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean by _"Automatic rebuild is not turned on"_? _Project > Build Automatically_? Is there anything that changes files in the workspace (Maven/Gradle, command line Git, etc.). I had something similar once and there it was a third-party plug-in that was used in a project and blocked the entire workspace even if I didn't touch that project at all. Which additional plug-ins do you have installed?

Comment: @howlger Yes, Build Automatically, sorry, should've used the official name. No I don't think there is anything that changes files. The project is very simple, no maven, just Java. No additional plugins, I think, well, Subclipse, but I didn't get that to work so I don't use it really, doesn't seem activated. This phenomenon occurs only sporadically, and renaming compilation units and moving seems to cause it sometimes. It self-heals sometimes, after some number of slow and annoying full rebuilds.

Comment: @john16384 The project is very simple, no maven, just Java, as detailed above. Maybe I could strip the two jars I use. But the problem went away, as it has before, but it will probably reappear... What might be different is that the number of source files is rather large, something like 25k.

Comment: _Project > Build Automatically_ means incremental build on save. Switching this off is not recommended for Java. Make sure to use the latest version of Eclipse (currently 2019-03) as such things have been improved (reduction of cases that block the entire workspace).

Comment: If it is such a simple project, then why does a build take long at all?  Aside from the fact that `Build Automatically` should be always on for Java, even building a few 1000 source files only takes like 5-10 seconds here.  If you can share the project somewhere, I can take a closer look.

Comment: @john16384 It's a simple project in the sense that there's only java. But perhaps not 'such a simple project'. I counted the source files, seems to be ~32k of them. My computer is 5 years old, takes 2 min to compile from scratch (so ~16kCU/min, almost 0.3kCU/s or 3k/10s). Two min is _really_ annoying when this nonsense repeats. It's not a problem as long as Eclipse doesn't get stuck like this, and it usually works fine, so I'll take my chances for now. I don't think I can share the project, and I am pessimistic about debugging it anyway, but I appreciate your offer to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Update 2: well it's been beach-balling again a few times. But this seems to work, (ie has worked twice in a row for me now), and seems to make sense:

Start build, but cancel somewhere in the middle. Then start build again.

The idea being that if a build starts in the bad state, there's a good chance that it ends in the bad state again, for whatever reasons. But cancelling in the middle might stop it from ending in the bad state. So we can restart the build in a better state.

---

Original: I think I figured it out. There is an error message with a stack trace, 
containing a DirectoryNotEmptyException. I suspect that under some conditions, a ".DSStore" file (a Finder/OSX/macOS hack) may stop the build process from deleting a directory in the target tree. This doesn't explain why it sometimes resolves itself, but maybe it's a timing issue. I think I one could make a script to find and delete all ".DSStore" files when this happens.

---

Update: the issue resurfaced, badly. Clean, close project, restart Eclipse, no avail. However, deleting target/classes worked in the end. (Weird, doesn't 'clean' do that? Deleting was slow as _, maybe that's why? I'll do a 'mv target/classes trash/' or something next time instead, see if that's ok with Eclipse). This note be useful to some fellow Eclipse user. Or myself, sadly :).